# Fastapi - UploadFile not working with HTML forms while it works in Swagger /docs

Tags: python, html, forms, file-upload, fastapi

I'm trying to replicate uploading a file which **works** with the `/docs` of Swagger/Fastapi and process it with Pandas. However, I get different types of errors when I'm trying it with HTML forms and it doesn't process the uploaded file. The last code I tried is the below and it gives back a `405 Method not Allowed` error.

```
@app.get("/upload-test/")
def form_post(request: Request):
    """Displays the form to create a project"""
    return templates.TemplateResponse('upload-alerts.html', context={'request': request})


@app.get("/upload-test/file")
def form_post(request: Request):
    """Displays the form to create a project"""
    return {"message": "Upload success"}


@app.post("/upload-test/")
async def form_post(request: Request,
                    file: UploadFile = File(...)
                    ):
    """Uploads the file and processes it in Pandas"""
    contents = await file.read()
    test_data = io.BytesIO(contents)
    df = pd.read_csv(test_data, sep=";")
    df.to_sql("alert_test", if_exists="replace", con=database.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, index=False)
    return {"filename":file.filename}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form action="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="bg-light p-5 rounded-lg m-3">
            <label for="file" class="form-label">File Input</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" name="file">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-light rounded-lg m-3">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button submit"><i class="bx bxs-cloud-upload"
                    style="font-size:1.4em;"></i> Upload Alerts</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.. :/

### **UPDATE**

Thanks to fchancel's answer I found that I had to change the following lines:

```
@app.get("/upload-test")  # So remove the last forward slash in get
@app.post("/upload-test")  # Remove also the last forward slash in post
```

In the HTML change the form action to "upload-test" to match it to the get/post:

```
<form action="upload-test" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive a 405 error because `<form action="file" method='post'....>` has the `post` method while your `"/upload-test/file "` endpoint is a GET. So, indeed, the 405 error makes sense.

So, you need to match the method between your `form` and your endpoint.

Comment: Actually the endpoint has both `get` and `post`. How will I be able to `post` then? I have the same logic for another page with regular form data (so no uploading files) and that works like this..

Comment: In my opinion your form `<form action ="file"...>` refers to the endpoint `" /upload-test/file "` which therefore only has the GET method

Comment: Thanks to your comments I got an idea, I will update it in my question. Thank you fchancel!